# Foreign kKey constraint SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to receive some feedback to know if my syntax is correct. If it is wrong what can I do to improve it?

```
ALTER TABLE Person
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Country 
    FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES Country(CID) 
            ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and I get this error:

> Cannot create the foreign key "FK_Country" with the SET NULL
>   referential action, because one or more referencing columns are not
>   nullable.

Comment: Why ask us when it takes 5 seconds to try and see...

Comment: Show us the table definitions for both Person and Country.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest you include both the names of both the referencing and referenced tables in the foreign key constraint name (e.g. `FK_Person_Country`) rather than just the referenced table. That way, you can have other tables reference the Country table as a foreign key without name conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clearly says the cause. You can't set null to the `Person.CID` when parent `Country` is deleted since the `Person.CID` is not nullable.

You have two options:

1. Make your `Person.CID` column as nullable
2. Make `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead of `ON DELETE SET NULL`. It will mean that the child data (`Person`) will be deleted when the parent data (`Country`) will be deleted.